# Switching languages in Magento doesn't show correct language

Tags: magento2, language, switcher

When switching between languages on this page:
http://x5-mail.com/
From Dutch to English. Dutch is the base language.

The buttons on top aren't translated.

Anyone familiar with this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Refresh page & Check in other browser Or incognito tab.

It seems like buttons translated.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Tried your suggestion on different clients and browsers but no succes so far.

Comment: Try with proxy & check if its ok.